# How can I play music from my iPod touch to my computer without using iTunes?

Tags: itunes, ipod

And also, how can I use the Apple Remote app? It's crashing and won't connect to iTunes.

Comment: The body of your question is a question in and of itself and should be asked separately.

Comment: @Suzyana When you say "play" do you mean stream music from one device to the other or transfer music from one to the other ?

Answer (score 1):

You can download [Sharepod](http://www.sharepod.com) to do this.

After downloading, make sure your iPod is plugged in and iTunes is *not* open. If the application does not recognize your iPod, it will give you a link to a page that should have a solution (though you probably won't have this problem).

You can select a folder to put your iPod music in or create a new one. If you would like to put all your music into the folder use <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all the songs in the list. Otherwise, you can select one song at a time, or hold down <kbd>control</kbd> and click on each song.

Once your music has finished transferring, you can play it in the application of your choice.

Comment: Not sure whether the OP uses Windows

Comment: Unclear if they were looking to stream the music to their computer (sounds like it?) or actually transfer it, as Sharepod does. That said their question is pretty clearly asking for a software recommendation ("without using iTunes").